# Bulk Insert into iphone sqlite database

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Hi i am using follwing code to insert bulk data from arrays into sqlite db...but it is extremely slow...please advise...
Am I using the right approach?

sqlite3 *db1=nil;
    db1 = [One2GuideUAppDelegate getNewDBConnection];

```
sqlite3_stmt *init_statement = nil;
@try
{   


    if(init_statement == nil)
    {
        const char *sql = "insert into tblBrand(intBId,intVersion,intLikes,intDontLikes,strName,strDesc,strWebsite,intEst,strFounder,strLogo,strThumbnail) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db1, sql, -1, &init_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0,@"Error: Failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.",sqlite3_errmsg(db1));  
    }

    for(int br=0;br<[brands count];br++)
    {
        BrandVO *brandVO=[brands objectAtIndex:br ];
        NSString *brandID=brandVO.brandID;
        NSString *brandVer=brandVO.brandVersion;
        NSString *brandLikes=brandVO.likes;
        NSString *brandDontLikes=brandVO.dontLikes;
        NSString *brandName=brandVO.name;
        NSString *brandDesc=brandVO.description;
        NSString *brandWeb=brandVO.url;
        NSString *brandEstb=brandVO.establishedYear;
        NSString *brandFounder=brandVO.founders;
        NSString *brandLogo=brandVO.logoURL;
        NSString *brandthumb=brandVO.thumbnailURL;





    sqlite3_bind_int(init_statement, 1, [brandID intValue]);
    sqlite3_bind_int(init_statement, 2, [brandVer intValue]);
    sqlite3_bind_int(init_statement, 3, [brandLikes intValue]);
    sqlite3_bind_int(init_statement, 4, [brandDontLikes intValue]);
    sqlite3_bind_text(init_statement, 5,[brandName UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(init_statement, 6,[brandDesc UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(init_statement, 7,[brandWeb UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_int(init_statement, 8,[brandEstb intValue]);
    sqlite3_bind_text(init_statement, 9,[brandFounder UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(init_statement, 10,[brandLogo UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(init_statement, 11,[brandthumb UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(init_statement))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db1));

    sqlite3_reset(init_statement);
        }

}

@catch (NSException *ex) 
{
    @throw ex;
}
@finally 
{
    if(init_statement)sqlite3_finalize(init_statement);
    sqlite3_close(db1);
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your insert statements in transactions with `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `END TRANSACTION`. This usually speeds up bulk inserts a lot.

Comment: I guess we can not use the same(Begin and End transactions) while fetching data....
I am facing similar speed problem while fetching the data from the db...
Please advise on it...

Comment: Check if you have indexes for the columns you are querying.

Comment: I havent created any indexes for the column i am specifying...I guess it is done at the time of database creation...How to go about it??

Comment: Refer to http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html or use a GUI tool like SQLite Manager or Base (there are several).